# SQL запрос (кол-во заказов за каждый день)

Tags: mysql, sql

есть табличка из 2-х колонок:

```
order_id | time_order
1 | 2018-10-10 00:00:00
2 | 2018-10-11 01:01:01
4 | 2018-10-12 02:02:02
5 | 2018-10-12 03:03:03
6 | 2018-10-13 04:04:04
---
7 | 2018-10-14 05:05:05
...
```

Есть дни когда более одного заказа, а есть когда 0 заказов и соответственно нет записей с этой датой.

Помогите плз написать запрос, по результату которого можно получить строку c количеством заказов за каждый день интервала вида: 1,1,2,1,0,1...

делаю такой запрос, но в нем не учитываются те дни временного интервала где 0 заказов:

```
SELECT DATE(time_order), COUNT(*)
FROM orders
WHERE DATE(time_order) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY DATE(time_order);
```

Благодарю!

Comment: *в нем не учитываются те дни временного интервала где 0 заказов* Сервер не умеет показывать данные, которых у него нет. Генерируйте таблицу дат без пропусков. Как? зависит от версии сервера... не поленитесь указать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае будет что-то типа

```
SELECT DATE(time_order), COUNT(*)
FROM orders, (      select 0 x 
              union select 1 
              union select 2
              union select 3
              union select 4
              union select 5 
              union select 6 ) x
WHERE DATE(time_order) = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL x.x DAY
GROUP BY DATE(time_order);
```

Для версии 8+ набор дат генерируется рекурсивным CTE.